# Union of linear inequalities cover whole space?

Tags: linear-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control, covering

We have $n$ variables $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n$ such that $a_i\geq a_{i+1}$. 
There are $k$ sets of linear inequality constraints on the $a_i$. 
I need to check that any choice of $a_i$ satisfies at least one of the k sets of constraints.

If I see it correctly, essentially I would need to check that the union of the feasible sets of the linear inequalities covers the subset defined by the $a_i$ of interest.

What would be the simplest way to do this?

$k=5$, $n=5$ and each set of constraints has about 5~10 (maybe redundant) constraints.

Comment: I believe if the $n$'th homology of the union of the $k$ sets is trivial (you can compute this using the nerve theorem), you only need to check that they cover the boundary of the region you're interested in. Then induct on each face of the boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the problem. 
In summary, one has to check that the union of the polyhedra is convex. 
If their union is convex, the union is equal to their envelope. 
These problems can be solved using linear programming.

Convexity recognition of the union of polyhedra
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772101000049

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (partially described) method which should work in principle. For it to be practical might require some added efficiency. I have actually used it in certain special cases with $n=3$.

Consider the equalities corresponding to all the inequalities. These correspond to hyperplanes which divide $\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$ into cells with faces of lower dimensions. For $n=2$ imagine finitely many planes defining cells (some unbounded) ,convex polygons (some unbounded) open intervals and (corner) points. Only when you cross one of these hyperplanes does an inequality change. Make an inventory of all the faces.  Then check at each corner and an interior point of each interval,face,cell etc. to find if some set of inequalities holds. If you have even 5 sets of 5 constraints  in 6 variables this gives potentially $\binom{25}{6}$ corners which is a lot.

In slightly more detail:

- Find all sets of $n$ equalities which define a point.
- For each one of those points first check your conditions $a_0 \ge a_1 \ge \cdots$ and ignore that point if they fail.
- otherwise, as an important first step, find if that corner satisfies some set of constraints. If any point fails you are done.

Here I will get vagu(er). First, if the various  inequalities are all strict then it is enough to just check that each intersection point alone satisfies some set. Even if some inequalities are weak, if at each intersection point some set holds with all the inequalities in that set strictly satisfied, that is enough. Otherwise we have the tasks of checking the immediate vicinity of each intersection point AND avoiding checking every face once for each corner. I'll ignore the second task (although this might be crucial for getting things done) We are left with the situation that at each intersection point one or more sets of inequalities holds **but** in each of these sets some of the inequalities hold with equality (i.e. are used in describing the point). I'll just say that one might systematically relax one equality at a time in each direction, see which sets stay satisfied and iterate.

Comment: Thanks for the description, I needed to be 100% sure it was right, so I could not use it. But I shortly after reading your solution I found the paper I that solves it.